# Chrome dispatch KeyboardEvent not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following code:

`index.html:`

```
<body >
    <input id="theInput" type="text" placeholder="type here"/>
</body>
```

`app.js:`

```
setTimeout(() => {
  var ev = document.createEvent('Events');
  ev.initEvent('keypress', true, true);
  ev.keyCode = 72;
  ev.which = 72;
  ev.charCode = 72;
  ev.key = 'h';
  ev.code = 'h';
  var returnValue = document.querySelector('#theInput').dispatchEvent(ev);
  console.log('returnValue', returnValue);
}, 2000);
```

I also tried this method (and a few other variations which none seem to work):

```
setTimeout(() => {
      var evt = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {code: 72, key: 72, keyCode: 72, charCode: 72, which: 72});;
      const returnValue = document.querySelector('#theInput').dispatchEvent(evt);
      console.log('returnValue', returnValue);
    }, 2000);
```

My problem is that the returnValue of the `dispatchEvent` is `true`, but the input's value still stays empty (I also make sure I focus the input before the 2 secs if that makes any difference).

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/37hcynxw/

Comment: can you tell me what is the expected return value from the code

Comment: true. and it returns true, but the input is empty